# Store layers in gitlab ci docker executor

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm working on gitlab CI at my project, and I created image to make my tests and builds. When I ran it in docker executor every job needs to download images from beggining. Is there any way to cachee/store that layers at host? like cache? I tried store /var/lib/docker/aufs but I guest its not everythink. Can't find any solution anywhere. Anyone has that problem before? How to work with it?

**gitlab-ci.yml**

`phpunit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -w /var/www -v $(pwd):/var/custom --rm phpunit/phpunit:4.8.5`

**gitlab-ci.yml with volumes from**

`phpunit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -w /var/www -v $(pwd):/var/custom --rm --volumes-from {image_from other build} phpunit/phpunit:4.8.5`

Comment: Did you try putting this line:  `volumes = ["/var/lib/docker"]` in the `[runners.docker]` section of gitlab-ci-runner's `config.toml` file? Would also need automatic caching disabled using `disable_cache = false`

Comment: Yes I did it and after 2 hours my runner was out of space. Becouse every job was caching all the layers but also volumes...

Comment: I can't test it myself right now, but what about mounting a volume like this: `volumes = ["/data/runner/:/var/lib/docker:rw"]`. Obviously only one runner per host allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option that works best would be to use a dedicated long-running docker:dind container like this:

```
docker run --privileged --name gitlab-dind -d --restart=always  docker:dind
```

(add --storage-driver=overlay2 if your host supports it!)

Then modify config.toml as follows:

```
[runners.docker]
  tls_verify = false
  image = "docker:latest"   <--------
  privileged = false     <--------
  disable_cache = false
  volumes = ["/cache"]
  links = ["gitlab-dind:docker"]   <-----------
  shm_size = 0
[runners.cache]
```

And remove

```
services:
- docker:dind
```

from .gitlab-ci.yml

If you want to run a docker container from .gitlab-ci.yml, you can do it like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: phpunit/phpunit:4.8.5
  script:
  - cd your_source && phpunit
```

Note I am guessing about the last line, since I don't know phpunit.

Comment: Yes it would be great but I can not mount dir when Im doing docker run in container., it looks like that:

 docker run -w /var/www -v $(pwd):/var/custom --volumes-from=trunk_$CI_PIPELINE_ID composer/composer run-script post-install-cmd -- skip-application skip-config skip-upgrade skip-assets

But custom is empty then :(

Comment: I tried mount host dir to gitlab-dind and add it to config toml but still no success. Maybe there are some ready to use solutions?

Comment: More information is needed. Please expand your question with more detail, including the .gitlab-di.yml file you are using. The solution I have given definitely should re-use images during a docker build. I have it running.

Comment: What I need:
- I should store and reuse images - your solution solve this problem
- when my script is run I want to run docker image with mounted dir from container, but when I do that my container has empty dir, no files from container are in my image.

`phpunit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -w /var/www -v $(pwd):/var/custom --rm phpunit/phpunit:4.8.5`

Comment: I put part of gitlab-ci in my question.

Comment: I extended my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, but have one last case, again updated in main post. You see I want to run container with volume from another container ;>

Comment: I suppose you want to run unit tests. Wouldn't it be better to run those from your source tree? If you run it the way I suggested, your git tree would be available inside the container without you needing to mount it.

Comment: Your solution has more problem for me, when I want to make something with my files, or maybe git or smth, gitlab has no credentials git etc. So I need to use my custom private image instead, but there I want to run phpunit or maybe i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: You mean that while building you want to pull from an external repo? Because while building obviously your own repo is already cloned and available.

Answer (score 0):

OK I tried get this around, by making my service with volume

`FROM docker:dind
RUN mkdir /gitlab-runner
VOLUME /gitlab-runner`

And when run gitlab ci docker executor I mount volumes from docker with command

`gitlab-ci-multi-runner exec docker phpunit --docker-volumes-from "gitlab-dind" --docker-links "gitlab-dind:docker" --builds-dir "/gitlab-runner"`

But dunno why my docker image and docker service are not sharing volume, any ide? Gitlab mout there somethink itself? or it has no connection besides --docker-volumes-from?

Comment: You keep extending the original question with more questions. I think it would be better if you create a new stack overflow question, and - since you said my answer solved your problem - mark my answer as correct?